# Making sure a thread finishes before going on (using Tasks) and making it sleep

Tags: c#

My program has a thread that executes commands based on user input. Sometimes, the commands can take a while to run.

So I need to start a thread for the long running tasks in order to allow the user to continue working.

After Googling for a bit, I found tasks, and made the code below:

```
    private Thread t_Thread;

    private void startTask()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting");

        Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                Thread.Sleep(500); // Is this right?
            }
        });

        Task.WaitAny(t);

        Console.WriteLine("Ending");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t_Thread = new Thread(() => startTask());

        t_Thread.Start();
    }
```

It seems to work okay but I'm unsure if I'm doing it right. Something tells me I've approached this wrong. Did I?

Comment: No, creating a task inside a thread and waiting that task to finish doesn't make any sense to me. *"After Googling for a bit, I found tasks, and made the code below"*: Google more...

Comment: possible duplicate of [BackGroundWorker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633666/backgroundworker)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx). It has a method `RunWorkerAsync()` which causes its `DoWork` event to be thrown; all of `DoWork`'s event handlers are executed in a different thread.

When the work is done, the `BackgroundWorker` throws its `RunWorkerCompleted` event, which you can listen to back on the UI thread.

In the mean time, the main form should be responsive to user input. If you *don't* want to accept user input, you can just disable all the controls before calling `RunWorkerAsync`, and re-enable them in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler.

Answer (score 1):

If your program is supposed to stop and wait until the task finishes then you shouldn't be using threads.  Instead just change the cursor to an hourglass and execute it in the main thread.

Other than that you will likely want to evaluate why things take so long and determine if the application is really supposed to sit there until it's done.

Comment: It is, some commands are like the AutoIT WinWait()... waiting for a certain window to come to focus, and the user needs to be able to still use the main form, hence the separate thread.

Comment: @duckwizzle: Your comment here is radically different from the one in your question that says "only let that thread execute until it finishes".  So either you are going to allow them to use the main form and therefore don't need to stop them; or you stop them completely while the new form loads...  Which is it?

Comment: Sorry about that. I should have been more specific. The form that calls the commands has to be use able to be used at all time so I put commands that would normally freeze the form while processing into separate threads. While that kind of command is running, I need the command thread keep running until it's completed or aborted while keeping the form free to use. After it's done it's work, then it can go on update the UI or whatever. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @duckwizzle: I updated your question to make more sense based on these comments. Jeremy has the right answer.